# Is there any known issue with horizontal placement of entries in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

Making the layout of the settings page in my `Xamarin` app, I noticed that the text inside the `Entries`couldn't be seen unless I clicked on the `Entry`.
I made different tests, recreating the whole structure and came to the conclusion that when two entries are displayed non-vertically, this thing happens.
Maybe I am doing something wrong and I just can't see it (likely because I made a lot of research in the internet but didn't found anything), so this is the `XAML` page where I reproduce the error.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.SettingsPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:SettingsViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label  Text="User information"
                    FontSize="Large"/>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Name*"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Label Text="Name*"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Label Text="Name*"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Label Text="Name*"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="Name*"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Label Text="Name*"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Label Text="Name*"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Label Text="Name*"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

As you can see, the two `StackLayouts` are exactly the same, except that the first one has `Orientation`set to `Horizontal` and the second one to `Vertical`.
All the `Entries` have their data binding set to the same public property, this means that the value should be the same for any of them. Now, when I go to my settings page, the first `StackLayout` shows empty entries inside it.
The second `StackLayout` shows entries with correct string inside of it.
If I click on an `Entry` inside the first `StackLayout` to enter text inside it, its content is displayed.
I tried the same thing using a `Grid` and the problem persists.
I'm executing this on `UWP`, but I don't know if this happens also on `Android` and `iOS`.
Is there any known issue with this? Did anyone try to display entries horizontally? 'Cause I couldn't find any example of doing this in the right way, if there is one.

I also provide the code of the `ViewModel`, just in case.

```cs
using MyApp.Models;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public SettingsViewModel()
        {

        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return Preferences.Get(Consts.PREF_NAME, ""); }
            set
            {
                Preferences.Set(Consts.PREF_NAME, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the first Horizontal Stacklayout, put the stack layout inside the scrollview so that all of your entries and label will accomodate the space that it needs and you will be able to scroll through them.

Comment: @NirmalSubedi Thank you, I was sure I was missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works fine for me. I have just enclosed your code inside a ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="MyApp.Views.SettingsPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:SettingsViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label  Text="User information"
                FontSize="Large"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="Name*"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Text="Name*"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Text="Name*"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Text="Name*"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="Name*"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Text="Name*"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Text="Name*"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Text="Name*"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

I test it on both iOS and UWP side and it all works well. I think you should pay attention to the codes where you assign the value to `SettingsViewModel.Name`. Here is some code you can refer:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model m = new model();
        m.Name = "name_1";
        BindingContext = m;
    }
}

class model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public model()
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {

        get { return Preferences.Get("Consts.PREF_NAME", ""); }
        set
        {
            Preferences.Set("Consts.PREF_NAME", value);
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
               {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
                }           
        }
    }
}
```

And the results:

[image]

[image]